# what's the meaning of 'input_length'?

Tags: tensorflow

the data have 4 timestamps,but the embedding's input_length=3,so what's the meaning of input_length?

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0,0,0,0]])
emb = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=2, output_dim=3, input_length=3)
emb(data)
```

Comment: Is it working for you? I think it would be 4 in place of 3.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding),

> **input_length**: Length of input sequences, when it is constant. This
>   argument is required if you are going to connect Flatten then Dense
>   layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be
>   computed).

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=2, output_dim=3, input_length=4))
# the model will take as input an integer matrix of size (batch, input_length).

input_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0]])
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
output_array = model.predict(input_array)
print(output_array)
```

Above works fine, but if you change `input_length` to 3, then you will get below error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_input to
>   have shape (3,) but got array with shape (4,)